# How can I only resolve a component if there's another component in the current LifeTimeScope?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, autofac

I have an situation here that looks very like a "SELECT N+1" from the NHibernate world.

I'm creating an application ASP.NET MVC app and the **HomeController** needs an **IUserSignUpService**. The **IUserSignUpService** "lives" in the *Application Service Layer* where it is binded to the concrete class **UserSignUpService**.

The UserSignUpService has 2 dependencies:

```
public IUserRepository UserRepository { get; set; }
public Domain.Services.IUserSignUpService SignUpService { get; set; }

public UserSignUpService(IUserRepository userRepository, Domain.Services.IUserSignUpService signUpService)
{
    this.UserRepository = userRepository;
    this.SignUpService = signUpService;
}
```

When Autofac is resolving the **IUserSignUpService** that lives in the Application Service Layer, it needs to resolve the **IUserRepository** dependency that lives in the Persistence Layer and a **Domain.Services.IUserSignUpService** (I know, same name, but they are different) that lives inside the Domain and performs several actions before execute the INSERT SQL to the database.

The **IUserRepository** interface is implemented by the **UserRepository** class that needs an **ISession** instance to be injected via constructor.

My point here is:

If I keep using this approach, every time I receive a HttpRequest to the HomeController I'm going to start a new ISession (because it is a constructor dependency of UserRepository, which is a constructor dependency to IUserSignUpController which is a constructor dependency of HomeController).

I don't need everything every time. Maybe I could instruct Autofac to only resolve the ISession when there's an instance of the IUnitOfWork interface in the current LifeTimeScope.

Is it possible?

Comment: You've got 2 `IUserSignUpService` interfaces? One in the service layer and one in the domain layer? This will be really confusing for anyone working on your project. If they do different things (what they most certainly will), name them differently.

Comment: I will. Right now I'm doing a "mega refactoring" :). The IUserSignUpService from Application Service Layer is the "start point" that is coordinating various operations regarding the process of sign up (sending email, moving some files and etc) and the IUserSignUpService from the Domain is doing things related to the domain. There are several operations in domain level that need to be done before persisting the value to the database. It's very confusing to anyone that's looking from outside, I know! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test whether doing extra work to not construct an ISession is premature optimization. Is there a significant perf hit?

If so, you could wrap whatever constructor dependency that you "don't need every time" in a Lazy<> and [Autofac will delay instantiation](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/RelationshipTypes).

Comment: Right now I'm in the early stage of the development. I know it seems to be an premature optimization but I'm trying to avoid unnecessary database connections and transactions to Actions that does not require. Right now my infra is very light and I need to use the servers the best way I can. I'm asking this because there will be a lot of Actions that will hit the Cache most of the times, so I wont need a database unless my cache expires.

Comment: You kinda answered my question! Thank you for pointing the right way! Just to add a little more context here. I want to be able to control my database workflow from my Application Service Layer. I want as little information on the Controller as possible, because I'm going to have mobile clients and a Windows Service (and it's relative from *NIX world) consuming this code.